# visual studio git processing apply mailbox stuck

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

After Source Tree, I performed a patch application (which had merge conflicts).

After applying, I went to resolve conflicts in Visual Studio (vs19 and vs2022), but nothing can be fixed. Visual Studio does not work with GIT, the process (**processing: apply mailbox**) is always running (hung).

Restarting the studio didn't work.
You can delete the repository and re-upload it, but then downloading such a patch, this situation will arise again.

The conflict was resolved in the studio. But the commit button in GIT cannot be pressed, because the sending process (**processing: apply mailbox**) hangs.

Can this be fixed somehow?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aurlL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY6UX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkQWB.jpg)

Restarting the studio didn't work.
You can delete the repository and re-upload it, but then downloading such a patch, this situation will arise again.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened because a patch failed part way through. Resolve the issues then use:

```
git am --continue
```

Other options are to skip the current patch:

```
git am --skip
```

Or if you would rather restore the original branch and abort the patching operation:

```
git am --abort
```